# How does FastRCNN RoI Projection deals with multiple RoI overlaping?

Tags: computer-vision, faster-rcnn

I understand that the RoI are proposed in the original image with any specific algorithm and, then, projected directly on the output of a feature generator like an VGG net without the last pooling layer.

But the original image is really bigger than the output of the backbone net. VGG, for instance, uses 224x224 images for input against 7x7 for output. So there will be many RoI that will overlap and will converge to the same area in the smaller feature map. For instance, all the bounding boxes with less than 37 (227/7) pixels with a same center could be mapped to the same spot in the feature map, and so, have the same backbone net features.
I don't understand how does the model deal with this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.